# When scrolling Listview and stops at any item, it moves to top position android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I am getting items based on pagination.All items are displaying but problem is that when i stop scrolling at any position, it moves to top. Please help me to solve this. I have issue in `onscrolllistener` in `listview`.

My code is as follows:

```
int pagesize = 1;

private class MovieTop extends AsyncTask {

@Override
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
        Object... params) {
    try {
        return displayTopMovies();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> displayTopMovies()
        throws IOException {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder
            .append("https://movie.org/movie/popular?");
    stringBuilder.append("?api_key=" + "c68"+"&&page="+pagesize); //getting page increment
    URL url = new URL(stringBuilder.toString());
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        // Establish a connection
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");              conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response code is: " + responseCode + " "
                + conn.getResponseMessage());

        stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return parseTopMovies(stringify(stream));
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
  parsing been done here..
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parseTopMovies(String result) {
    String streamAsString = result;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(streamAsString);
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject jsonMovieObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE,
                    jsonMovieObject.getString("original_title"));
            results.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Error parsing JSON. String was: "
                + streamAsString);
    }
    return results;
}

}
   @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    update2((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) result);
    };


   //Here i am displaying result
   public void update2(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
   this.result.addAll(result);
   ListView listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.container);

   // Add results to listView.
   adapter = new UpcomingMovieAdapters(this, R.layout.upcoming,result);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   // here i am using notifyDatasetchanged.
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    try {

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                    int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (scrollState == 0) {
                    // Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");
                    if (pagesize <= 30) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Moving to top when scroll stopped at any item position..", 1000).show();
                        pagesize = pagesize + 1;

                            new MovieTop().execute();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: please post `TMDBNow_View` class

Comment: sorry now i edited. I am pointing new MovieTop().execute().

Comment: i updated full code here @shayanpourvatan http://pastie.org/9676487

Comment: you initialize adapter in each data, you must use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of create new object. if you need more help tell me to post better as answer

Comment: sorry can't get you. @shayanpourvatan will you please give with detailed one. so where to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: see my answer Spark, i hope you get my mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you create Adapter in each incoming data, your list scroll to first position, for handling this issue you need create your adapter just once then use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` for refreshing data.

in `onCreate` method use

```
 adapter = new UpcomingMovieAdapters(this, R.layout.upcoming,result);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then in async class use following code.

```
 public void update2(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
   this.result.addAll(result);

   // just use this line 
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're setting the adapter to the list repeatedly. You should only do this once, every time you set it the list view is reset to the top. Instead you need to have one instance of the adapter to update then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the list view to update itself.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your reply.see my update. I used but still have  problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that problem is in calling `new MovieTop().execute();` onScroll stopped, because data are parsed for next page, but Adapter is created again in `onPostExecute`.

If `this.result` is ArrayList with all results, try to use:

```
if(adapter == null) {
    adapter = new UpcomingMovieAdapters(this, R.layout.upcoming,result);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: still issue is there. it makes to hide items when start to scroll.

Comment: Sorry, try to use the same control for ListView.

Comment: I looked again and maybe you should add new items to adapter, not the arraylist. So try to use: `adapter.addAll(result)`